# How can I convert or view animated HEIF files?

Tags: software-rec

My Samsung Android phone has the option of saving images in HEIF format (i.e. `*.heic` files). These seem to have excellent compression compared to regular JPEG. In Linux, I can view HEIF files using [qt-heif-image-plugin](https://github.com/jakar/qt-heif-image-plugin), which wraps [libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif).

My phone also allows me to create animated HEIF files (what Samsung calls "motion photos").
Is there a way to view, convert, or edit these in Linux?

Comment: I am using Kubuntu and not everything automatically opens HEIF. `apt-get install heif-gdk-pixbuf heif-thumbnailer libheif1 gimagereader gpicview` I wrote a tiny script to convert to jpg with heif-convert, but I think they lose the motion . https://askubuntu.com/questions/958355/any-app-on-ubuntu-to-open-and-or-convert-heif-pictures-heic-high-efficiency-i

Comment: @oldfred The url you linked is not specifically about animated HEIF files. The script from your link says "NO LONGER MAINTAINED", but even so, if it converts to JPEG then presumably it doesn't deal with animated HEIF files?

Comment: I have Apple which uses HEIF, but all converted files are not animated. Not sure jpg supports animation. Perhaps converting to .mov, if that is even possible? If you want the annimation, you may just need heif.

Comment: @oldfred Yep, I don't really mind either way. Happy to work with animated HEIF directly if that's possible. Otherwise I'm happy to convert first.